# How to use distinct and MAX(id) in same query SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table "`batchtracing`" with 8999 rows for `batchno` for id 7434.
I want DISTINCT `batchno` for this table. For all DISTINCT`batcho` i have 47 rows.
For every `batchno` i want to get MAX(ID) but for every row.

My questions is: How can i have MAX(id) for every DISTINCT `batchno`

I try this but is not my solution, this put me for all rows same value at column id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT batchno,
                          (SELECT     MAX(id) AS Expr1
                            FROM          batchtracing) AS id
FROM         batchtracing AS batchtracing_1
WHERE     (contentid = '7434')
```

To get what i need i use 3 query, but i want just one because is slowly.
What i do now:

```
Step 1: SELECT DISTINCT batchno, batchstatus FROM batchTracing WHERE (contentid = " & contentid & ") AND (batchstatus = 'active') ORDER BY batchno

Step 2:SELECT MAX(id) AS Expr1 FROM batchTracing WHERE (batchno = '" & batchno & "') AND (contentid = '" & contentid & "')

Step 3: SELECT batchstatus FROM batchtracing WHERE id =  batchTracingID
```

This method is very slowly and i want just one query to result all this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use rownumber:

```
Select b.*
From (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by batchno order by id desc) as seqnum
     From batchtracing
    ) b
Where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: You think you can do for my example? I don't understand from this example

Comment: I need one example for contentid =  '7434')

Comment: @Vladut this query gets the row with the highest Id per batchno from batchtracing, so you can get your status etc from it as well. Just add `where contentid = '7434'` to the subquery.

Answer (score 3):

You're over complicating this - you just need to group by batch number

```
SELECT batchno, MAX(id)
FROM batchtracing
WHERE contentid = '7434'
GROUP BY batchno
```

If contentid is a numeric column, you should remove the quotes round 7434 to avoid unnecessary conversions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use `GROUP BY`.

```
select batchno, max(id)
  from batchtracing
 where contentid = 7434
 group by batchno
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need to do is use a `GROUP BY`:

```
Select  BatchNo, Max(Id) As Id
From    BatchTracing
Where   ContentId = '7434'
Group By BatchNo
```

Comment: And if want to put and column batchstatus?

Comment: @Vladut That is a different question entirely, to do that use [Gordon Linoff's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41720928/3393505).

Answer (score 1):

SELECT batchno, max(Id)
FROM batchTracing
Where ContentId = '7434'
GROUP BY batchno